# Soundcloud Javascript SDK sound not pausing

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

Using the Soundcloud JavaScript SDK I have successfully been able to grab my tracks and play them. My goal is to allow playing and pausing via clicking on one button (like a play/pause toggle). However, my issue is that when I click on the .SCbtn element, the song plays, and doesn't stop. My conditionals seem to be correct because I can see true and false making it into the console. Not quite sure why SC.sound.pause(); isn't working.

```
var is_playing = false;
var trackCont = function(trackNum){
SC.stream("/tracks/" + trackNum).then(function(sound){
    SC.sound = sound;
    if (is_playing === false){
        SC.sound.play();
        is_playing = true;
        console.log(is_playing);
    }else if(is_playing === true){
        SC.sound.pause();
        is_playing = false;
        console.log(is_playing);
    }
    });
}
$('body').on("click", ".SCbtn", function(){
    var theTrack = $(this).attr('id');
    trackCont(theTrack);
});
```

**Update**

[My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rmohan06/8s1emc32/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating things.  Here's a simple example:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script>
<button id="play">Play</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'XXXX'
});

var myPlayer;
var isPaused = false;
SC.stream('tracks/43377447').then(function(player){
            player.play()
            myPlayer = player;
        });

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (isPaused) {
        myPlayer.play()
        isPaused = false;
    } else {
        myPlayer.pause()
        isPaused = true;
    }
});
```

[Working JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/mmjLwqss/)

Comment: Thanks JAL! I like your answer but it only works for one track. My goal is to be able to get all ten of my tracks to play and pause. That's why my code above is passing a track number into the trackCont function to dynamically update the stream. I added a fiddle above that links to some code that is half way there. I am able to get my tracks to play but not pause. There is also a weird behavior where you have to click each track twice before it plays.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the toggle() method provided by Soundcloud for easiest implementation. See here: [https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget](http://Soundcloud%20HTML5%20Widget%20API)

Something like the below should do the trick:

```
var sc = SC.Widget(iframe);

$('body').on("click", ".SCbtn", function(){
    sc.toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Elliott! Looking at your link, this is specifically for the widget. I am trying to build something from scratch so I have more control over the look of my player.

Comment: @RobM that is exactly what the widget is.  Basically what you do is create an iframe to load the sounds to. mine is set to `display: none` so it doesn't show anything.  Then you build your player however you want and attach whatever methods you want - .toggle() .play() .pause(). seek() etc... You load sounds into your invisible iframe that soundcloud processes and plays through, but all of the controls are in your custom player

Comment: Ah! That is interesting. I totally didn't make that connection but it makes sense. I will try your approach tonight. Thanks for giving more detail.

Comment: I am able to successfully get the play/pause and prev/next methods to fire on the  iframe widget. But it's only for the playlist as a whole and not for each individual song. You can see my example at https://jsfiddle.net/Rmohan06/1aagyfkb/3/. Ideally I would like to have each track play and pause but I can't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: @RobM If you are putting a playlist into the widget that's all you can do with it. 
 In order to play and pause individual tracks, but also have them play continuously, you'll need to use the SC.Widget.Events method's that soundcloud also provides.  You can use the FINISH event to see when a track is finished to load in the next track, similar to how the playlist works.  This will also allow you to play and pause individual tracks as you'll have full control.

Comment: thanks for all your suggestions. I still can't get the single tracks to play or stop. Using the methods seem to only work for the playlist as a whole. I might need you to elaborate on "this will also allow you to play and pause individual tracks as you'll have full control."  It sounds like you have created a custom player before. I would be interested in seeing that code.