# Pause is behaving incorrectly in the SoundCloud Javascript API

Tags: javascript, promise, soundcloud

Note: Exactly this has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40074942/issues-playing-and-pausing-tracks-from-a-playlist-soundcloud-javascript-api), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833048/soundcloud-javascript-sdk-sound-not-pausing), without satisfactory answers.

I'll try to explain the problem better here, and you can also read TLDR below. [Here's](https://jsbin.com/tekijur/edit?html,js,console,output) a simple fiddle I created using Soundcloud JS sdk v3. I define global variables `playerGlobal` and `playingId`. During the first play, both of them are null, and clicking one of `play` or `playNext` buttons initializes those variables. Suppose, we click `play` first, the related track starts playing. When we click `pause` button soon after, `pause()` fires and uses the `globalPlayer` to pause the currently playing track. This works as expected.

When I click `playNext`, both global variables are updated as they should. The problem arises when I click `play` again. For some strange reasons, the track associated with `play` button plays from time starting at when I clicked `pause` above. When I click `pause`again, nothing happens.

**TLDR:** Click `play` -> `pause` -> `playNext`(works fine till here) -> `play`(strange remembering of last position happens) -> `pause`(nothing happens).

I'm including the snippet here as well.

```js
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'MmZKx4l7fDwXdlL3KJZBiJZ8fLonINga'
});

//Get player
function getPlayer(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    SC.stream(url)
      .then(player => {
        if (player.options.protocols[0] === 'rtmp')
          player.options.protocols.splice(0, 1);
        resolve(player);
      });
  });
}

//Global players and id to track current playing track
var playerGlobal = null;
var playingId = null;

function play() {

  var id = '1';

  //Resume playing if the same song is hit
  if (playerGlobal !== null && id === playingId) {
    console.log("-- using old player");
    playerGlobal.play();
    return;
  }
  //New player on a new song 
  var url = '/tracks/309689093';
  getPlayer(url)
    .then(player => {
      if (playerGlobal) playerGlobal = null;
      playerGlobal = player;
      console.log("-- new player created");
      playerGlobal.play();
      playingId = id;
    });
}

function pause() {
  playerGlobal.pause();
}

function playNext() {
  var id = '2';

  //Resume playing if the same song is hit
  if (playerGlobal !== null && id === playingId) {
    console.log("-- using old player");
    playerGlobal.play();
    return;
  }

  //New player on a new song 
  var url = "/tracks/309689082";
  getPlayer(url)
    .then(player => {
      if (playerGlobal) playerGlobal = null;
      playerGlobal = player;
      console.log("-- new player created");
      playerGlobal.play();
      playingId = '2';
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button onClick="play()">play</button>
  <button onClick="pause()">pause</button>
  <button onClick="playNext()">playNext</button>

  <script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm not sure why this wouldn't work. One of the ways I was able to make this work was by defining separate `player`, `pause` and `id` variables for both tracks. And then when a track is played after another, I set `seek` to position 0. [Here's](https://jsbin.com/tekijur/1/edit) it. The problem of course is, this is just for reference, my use case involves many more tracks, and I didn't want to define separate variables for them all, until I'm sure why above code doesn't work and that it is the only way. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Why wouldn't `.seek(0);` work on the `playerGlobal` as well?

Comment: Doesn't work. As you should see in my updated fiddle. No ideas.

Comment: by the way, avoid the Promise constructor anti-pattern in `function getPlayer`

Comment: @JaromandaX: thanks for pointing out. Didn't know it was considered anti-pattern. Read about it... now I know.